# Test using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, mockito

Here is my code and I want to know what's the best way to test using Mockito as I am creating couple of objects using new keyword.  can anyone guide me ?

```
public static PDDocument generatePDF(final String reportString, final String requestId) throws IOException {

        final PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

        final byte[] byteStr = reportString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final String str = new String(byteStr,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(str));

        try {

            // PDF box ceremony

            final TextToPDF textToPdf = new TextToPDF();
            textToPdf.setFont(PDType1Font.COURIER);
            textToPdf.setFontSize(10);

            textToPdf.createPDFFromText(document, reader);

            reader.close();
        } catch (final IOException ioException) {
            LOGGER.error("IO Exception while generating PDF for request id " + requestId, ioException.getMessage());
            throw ioException;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception while generating PDF for request id " + requestId, e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        return document;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you are using apache PDF box, aren't you? I am asking because I do not see references to other classes provided by you, but only to framework classes.

Comment: Yes I am using Apache PDF box api.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito is intended to mock the collaborators of the class/method you want to test. Note that it should be used only to mock the types you own.
In this case, you don't actually need Mockito.
An example, similar to yours, in which you could use Mockito, is this:

```
class PDFGenerator {

    private ITextToPdf textToPdf; // This is an hypotetical interface provided by you, for example used as a wrapper to easily change the underling framework

    public void setTextToPdf(ITextToPdf textToPdf) {
        this.textToPdf = textToPdf;
    }

    public static PDDocument generatePDF(final String reportString, final String requestId) throws IOException {

        final byte[] byteStr = reportString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final String str = new String(byteStr,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(str));

        try {

            IDocument document = textToPdf.createPDFFromText(reader);

            reader.close();

            return document;
        } catch (final IOException ioException) {
            LOGGER.error("IO Exception while generating PDF for request id " + requestId, ioException.getMessage());
            throw ioException;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception while generating PDF for request id " + requestId, e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }

    }
}
```

In this case, the test would be:

```
@Test
public void testGeneratePdf() throws Exception {
    ITextToPdf textToPdfMock Mockito.mock(ITextToPdf.class);
    PDFGenerator pdfGenerator = new PDFGenerator();
    pdfGenerator.setTextToPdf(textToPdfMock);

    Mockito.when(textToPdfMock.createPDFFromText(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(something);
    IDocument generatedDocument = pdfGenerator.generatePDF(createReportString(), "TestId");

    Mockito.verify(textToPdfMock, Mockito.times(1)).createPDFFromText(Mockito.any());
    Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(textToPdfMock);
    // Do also some standard junit asserts on the generatedDocument
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I agree as it's third party api , actually it's not needed Mockito. I will try the example you have given.. Thanks